# geth Sending payload over and over

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain

I'm working with a private chain. Sometimes after trying to create a contract it gets stuck spitting out this over and over:

```
I0616 15:17:12.778089   32745 http.go:157] Sending payload: [
    {
        "id": 9355,
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "result": []
    },
    {
        "id": 9356,
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "result": []
    },
    {
        "id": 9357,
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "result": []
    },
    {
        "id": 9358,
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "result": []
    }
]
```

The id keeps updating, all the rest says the same. This happens very quickly and the contract never seems to get mined.